# AWS cassandra nodes cloning

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax

I have built a single cassandra node on AWS and its working fine. We want to build 5 more of it so we have cloned the first one into 5 other cassandra servers. I would like to know what all the changes we possibly need to make so that they will run into 5 new cassandra servers.

1) delete all the data in data directories, saved_caches and commitlog
2) update cassandra.yaml file with listen, broadcast and rpc_addresses.
3) what change should we make at system level like hostname or gateway or any other things for the new nodes?????  Kindly suggest these, i don't have much knowledge of system administration. 
4) I have stopped the original node cassandra service and ds agent service before taking the clones.

please add any other things i need to change to make the cluster work with new 5 nodes.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Datastax has a guide for planning an [Amazon EC2 cluster](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/planning/planPlanningEC2.html). After reviewing the Datastax guide, make sure you configure the `cassandra.yaml` file with the correct options. If all of the nodes will have duplicate directory structures you can use the same `cassandra.yaml` file on each node. Note that making changes to the `cassandra.yaml` will require a restart.

For more information on configuration of the nodes in a single data center see " [Initializing a multiple node cluster in a single data center](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html)." For multiple data centers see "[Initializing a multiple node cluster, multiple data centers](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/initialize/initMultipleDS.html)."

If you follow the steps outlined in the documentation and guides you should be able to easily add new nodes to your instance.